# multiple activities and intents in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

**Hi guys**

i have simple android app with 3 activity A,B,C

A activity is the main activity and B,C are the childes.

A | -> B

A | -> C

i already know how to move to other activity by buttons
but i have strange problem 
when i start the app,i can only go to those activity for first time and when i press back btn to main activity & press button of another activity the app will crush and show this error **"Unfortunately, app has stopped."**

**For example**
when Main activity (a) is loaded i will click the btn of 2ndActivity (B)
and it will open 2nd activity successfuly

**But**

when i press back system btn and try to click the btn of 3rd activity (c)
the app will failed and show error

**note that** only each activity that click for first time will be lunch successfuly 
I mean if I click btn of C activity for first time then the activity B wont work and show error

**note** no error found in LogCat and app run correctly in emulators,problem will happen on some phone like my gs4 not all phone

sorry for my bad English

I need your help ,Thanks

My MainActivityA.java

```
 public class MainActivityA extends ActionBarActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar AB = getSupportActionBar();
    AB.hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainA);

    ImageButton b1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebtndb1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivityA.this, MainActivityB.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    ImageButton b2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebtndb3);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i2 = new Intent(MainActivityA.this, MainActivityC.class);
            startActivity(i2);
        }
    });
```

My MainActivityB

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar AB=getSupportActionBar();
    AB.hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/htm.html");



}
```

my MainActivityC

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar AB=getSupportActionBar();
    AB.hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity4);
}
```

my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivityB"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.activityB" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivityC"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.activityC" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: *no error found in Logcat*. Look again. Every app crash gets a stack trace written to logcat.

Comment: Remove the intent filter tags from activity B and C in the manifest file.

Comment: @adelphus app wont get crash in emulators ,logcat is clear

Comment: @ReazMurshed i did it, but still same problem occurred :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing your intent filter in your manifest to the full path of the classes

e.g

intent-filter

```
     action android:name="<full domain name here>.activityB"
```

intent-filter

```
     action android:name="com.myandroid.app.activityB"
```

try it for both activityB and activityC.

Comment: you point me the right way..the problem was with  manifest...but not that line you said...
I add this line to childs 
android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved

may be this could help someone beginner like me in future

I added this line to My  manifest

```
<activity 
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >

<meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.myandroid.app.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Thanks Guys

Answer (score -1):

If the back buttons aren't responding correctly you could always override them to go to the parent activity. Here is something you could do:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent goToParentIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(goToParentIntent);
}
```

Add this code to each of your child activities.

Comment: I try it for both child... after add that code to child activities the app still show error but after force stop the app will restart to main activity...nice idea but still same problem ocurred...
if the problem is back btn...so why it work correctly with first child click?!
the problem is the app work fine only for one child